# Merge Statement Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table with one column `iscurrent`, values are 0 and 1.

I am inserting rows to this table with a merge statement that is inserting or updating based on the value of `iscurrent`. For performance tuning I have created two partitions with 0 and 1 on that table. But the performance is not good enough.

How can I tune the merge statement? Every time it is merging thousands rows to million of rows. Will partitioning the table help?

Comment: can you post the statement? There is no inherent "slowness" in the `MERGE` statement. It's pretty much a built-in upsert.

Comment: So basically you will touch every row in the table? Either with an update or with an insert? You will have a hard time getting performance from that. 

Could you provide an example of your merge statement?

Comment: There is nowhere near enough info to help here.  You need to provide table structure, indexes, and the query you are running to even begin.

Comment: Please include the schema of your tables, the MERGE query itself, and a description of the data being processed.  Such as `5m records, 97% marked as isCurrent=1, merged with a table of 25,000 records, on average 50% are new inserts and 50% are updates`, or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a derived table as the source, start by tuning that select statement first, or put the results of the derived table into a physical table with the proper indexes.

```
MERGE myTargetTabe as TargetTable
USING (derived table statement goes here) SourceTable on .......
```

A merge statement will scan every row that meets the criteria you specify in the "ON" clause, if there are rows that you don't need to merge, then exclude the rows here. For example:

```
MERGE myTargetTabe as TargetTable
USING (derived table statement goes here) SourceTable on TargetTable.ID = SourceTable.ID and TargetTable.OtherColumn NOT IN (....)  and ...... or .... and so on.
```